# Composition class in Ruby: where to put, how many methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, composition, service-object

On my Rails backend, I want to reuse several methods in different model classes.

Google search points me towards Ruby composition.

I have two questions concerning good practice:

1. **How many methods** can go into a composition class?
   From [this](https://medium.com/aviabird/ruby-composition-over-inheritance-3ff786ad9e5d) article, the part "Composition to the Rescue", it sounds like **composition should only have one (non-private) method**.
   Is it correct, and why?
2. **Which folder** does the composition class file go?
   I read that service object goes to the `app/services` folder and concerns go to `app/models/concerns`. Which folder should be used for composition?

I understand that these are not strict rules, and I have searched but cannot get answers.
I would really like to know about good practice and your experience.
Thank you!

Comment: "A composition class" is not actually a thing on its own. It's merely a pattern of a class that references another class through an instance variable. That's not actually a criteria for how to organize the code.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification! Looks like what I really need is to read more about the different patterns to organize codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using composition, then you can add as many methods to a mixin or concern as you like.

I recommend only combining methods into a mixin or concern when they have a common use-case. And there should be an obvious title or name for the group of methods. You could, for example, have a concern for methods related to logging or auditing, another of authentication or authorization related methods, and another for shared methods related to handling uploaded files.

The de facto standard for composition mixins in Ruby on Rails is using `Concern` and the default location for model concerns is `app/models/concerns/...` and `app/controller/concerns/...` for controller concerns.

See ["Using Concerns" in the official Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#using-concerns) and [`ActiveSupport::Concern` in the Rails docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

Comment: I can really recommend Scheems article [Good Module Bad Module](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/good-module-bad-module) and the follow up [When To Be Concerned About Concerns](https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/when-to-be-concerned-about-concerns). Basically the gist of them is that extraction for the sake of extraction (reducing the number of lines) is rarely a good thing.

Comment: Mixins (or concerns) are not composition.

Comment: Thank you all for your explanation and comments. I will read more about the different patterns to organize codes. Now that I have some pointers and keywords, researching should be easier.